# Alfresco: Data Dictionary and My Company language

Tags: alfresco

I'm newbe in Alfresco. I correctly installed it (it's working fine :) ) and it's all in english but the Data Dictionary it's in italian and also the Company Home and My Home entries. How can I switch it to English?

thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco looks at your locale, and if your browser is english, it should present everything in english. check you language browser settings. Check this site for how to change the settings, it might not be accurate [link](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities#changing)

Comment: I think the names of things like Company Home are set at bootstrap time though, which may be what the user has seen?

Comment: Ooh that, but those are default in English I guess and hardcoded maybe ;)

Comment: There is a file called bootstrap-spaces.properties in Alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages folder. Check which one you have, these are used in the bootstrap.

Comment: I believe the names get set based on the locale in use the first time the repository starts up. After that, they're fixed in that language

Comment: Yes, so or he could either re-install, or just rename the folders ;)

Comment: I actually didn't speak about the browser message but the repository language. It's in italian and if I try to execute a web script searching for "Company Home" it doesn't work but it works with "Homepage dell'azienda". Do you know if there is a way to recreate the repository using a different language?

Comment: Hi, look at the third comment of mine. There is a bootstrap-spaces.properties which is used on bootstrap. So what you could do is: clean the alf_data folder and drop the DB. And delete all other bootstrap-spaces_xx_xx.properties files, so Alfresco will only use the default one.